# Creating and running executable by hand

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

Just for interest sake, I want to compile and run the simplest C program by hand;

```
//t.c

int main() {
       return 0;
}
```

So I want to do:

- `$ cpp t.c` : should do nothing in this case, since no preprocessing to be done
- `$ cc1 t.c` : should compile `t.c` -> `t.s`
- `$ as -o t.o t.c` : should assembe `t.s` -> `t.o`
- `$ ld t.o` : should produce executable `a.out` (nothing really to be done)

The problem I'm having is with `as`, since running the final command yields:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000000400b0
```

What's going on? I purposly left out `libc` to keep this as simple as possible, but I don't understand what's happening. What flags am I missing?

Comment: oh, do I need to link in `crt1.o` ?

Comment: yes, crt1.o will provide _start

Comment: And you really should have an intermediate file after pre-processing, because it's the pre-processor that will remove your comment at the top (although passing it through probably won't harm the next pass).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Indeed, the compiler accepts “pre-processed” files that still contain comments. GCC's pre-processor even has an option to leave them in if you need to for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bit more to loading and executing a program. As you can guess from the linker output, execution starts not at `main`, but at `_start`, which is provided by the CRT (C runtime) library that is bundled with the compiler and gets linked with your code behind the scene.

[Here](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) and [here](http://linuxgazette.net/issue84/hawk.html) are some overviews of what's going on at program startup on Linux.

Do `cc -v -Wall` on your dummy source to see all the required steps in detail.

Comment: Great, great links. Thanks so much. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said **simplest** program, here is a real hack.

This is for Ubuntu 12.04, running x86_64. If you have something else, then this might give you a hint what to do.

```
mkdir hack_code
cd hack_code
cp /usr/lib/ldscripts/elf_x86_64.x ldsimple.x
```

Now modify `ldsimple.x` to say `ENTRY(main)` instead of `ENTRY(_start)` in the beginning.

Create this `mymain.c`:

```
int main(void)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "movq $60, %rax\n"  /* call sys_exit */
        "movq $2,  %rdi\n"  /* return code   */
        "syscall"           /* call kernel to exit program */
    );
    return 0;
}
```

And then:

```
gcc -c mymain.c
ld -o mymain -T./ldsimple.x mymain.o
```

Voila: You now have got a program which does not use any library etc.